# reducing number of JVM's used by mpi

Tags: multithreading, jvm, cluster-computing, openmpi, hpc

I'm writing a program in java to run on a HPC using [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), but I have this feeling I'm wasting the resources because of the way [open-mpi](http://www.open-mpi.org) works. I'm actually not at all sure about how it works, but I assume `mpirun -n 10 java myProgram.java` starts 10 times myProgram on different nodes/cores/etc. (depending on the binding) every time. This also means, for as far as my understanding of JVM reaches, 10 JVMs are running.

After some test-runs with my program, using the default settings (binding to cores and packing everything as much as possible on 1 node), I realised memory-usage was very poor and came to the conclusion I would have to do something about the multiplicity of the JVMs. I tried to loosen the binding from cores to nodes, but then I don't use all possible processing power. I already tried to use multithreading to solve that problem as well, but I read [(somew)here](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2014/04/24261.php) that's not one of the best ideas either (but I'm still trying to find out a way around).

So my question is:
**Does there exist a way to link every node with only one JVM, using open-mpi?**
*alternative*: How can I make better use of the memory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [documentation of open-mpi](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=java)  specifies that open-mpi has a java interface. It provides a wrapped compiler `mpijavac`  and mpirun has been updated to detect the java command. To build this interface, open-mpi must have been configured with `--enable-mpi-java` : have you done it ? Could you try the `--showme` option to check if mpirun corresponds to open-mpi ?

Comment: I did do that, but as most of these commands are just wrappers, I assume I get as much JVMs as I defined processes with the `-n` flag. I still only assume that, because I can't find whether the wrappers would optimise anything for java.

Comment: Yes, you do get as much JVMs as MPI ranks. That's what MPI is all about - portable **interprocess** communication (though not specifically stated in the standard, virtually all popular MPI implementations treat ranks as separate processes). If starting one JVM per MPI process is too much, you should go hybrid, i.e. mix threaded programming with MPI.

Comment: Is there really no other way to achieve the same/similar results? I already tried hybrid, but open-mpi doesn't seem to fully support this (see the conversation I linked to in my question).

Comment: Open MPI fully supports `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` and `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`, which means that as long as you are not calling into MPI from multiple threads at the same time, it will function correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Hristo Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/hristo-iliev) already mentioned in the comments, the hybrid approach solves my problem. To avoid having to use `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`, I distributed the work statically. The program can then be run with `mpirun --map-by ppr:1:node --bind-to board java <java-program>` in order to limit the number of processes run on one node.